# Routing the URL using values from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller `streams_controller` and a model `streams`.

```
class StreamsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @stream = Stream.new
  end

  def create
    @stream = Stream.new(params[:stream])
    if @stream.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
        redirect_to @stream
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end


  def show
    @stream = Stream.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

and

```
class Stream < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    before_save { |stream| stream.name = name.downcase }

    has_secure_password
.
.
.
```

Basically to work the show method, I have to go `localhost/streams/[id]` where [id] is the id of the particular Stream. Would it be possible to reroute the URL to go something like this: `localhost/[name]` where [name] is the :name attribute of the Stream model?

So basically a new URL would be created every time a new Stream is created, and it would correspond to the name of the Stream in the database.

How would I go about implementing this?

Anyways, any help or thoughts greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this should work so long as you can guarantee that none of the stream names will clash with any of the controller names.

Comment: @cdesrosiers Yeah I'll look out for that. But the main problem is, how would I implement the actual URL routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the `streams` part of the url as short as possible, but not empty (to avoid collisions in the case of using just names instead of ids).

```
resources :streams, path: 's'
```

Url `/s/stream-a` isn't that big compromise.

About using name instead of id in your url see [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid).

Comment: Do I really have to use FriendlyID? I was sort of hoping that this sort of thing would be built in. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @DanishM The Railscast mention the overriding of `to_param` method in your model: `def to_param  "#{id} #{name}".parameterize end`. You'll get url lilke: `/s/2-foo-bar` where `2` refers to id and `foo-bar` represents the model's `name`. With this approach you don't have to modify anything in your controller (`Model.find(params[:id]` will still be working as before, but links will be much more descriptive).

Answer (score 2):

The line `match '/:name' => 'streams#show'` would give you params[:name] and route to the show action in streams. If there happen to be any conflicts with controller names, you can place this line towards the end of the routes.rb file so that the appropriate controller action takes precedence. Of course, it'd be best to make sure those clashes don't happen in the first place.

Comment: Alright, now how do I get the URL to work? It's currently requiring me to put localhost/[id] still.

Comment: What do you see when you run rake routes?

Comment: `streams GET    /streams(.:format)          streams#index
POST   /streams(.:format)          streams#create
new_stream GET    /streams/new(.:format)      streams#new
edit_stream GET    /streams/:id/edit(.:format) streams#edit
stream GET    /streams/:id(.:format)      streams#show
            PUT    /streams/:id(.:format)      streams#update
            DELETE /streams/:id(.:format)      streams#destroy`

Comment: If you added the line to the routes.rb, there should be this line coming up in rake routes `/:name(.:format) streams#show`

Answer (score 0):

You can load streams in the routes. For example:

```
begin
  streams = Streams.all.map{|s| s.slug}
  match '/:stream' => 'streams#show', :stream => Regexp.new( "(#{streams.join('|')})" )
rescue Exception => e
  logger = Logger.new STDOUT
  logger.warn e.message
end
```

Note, I used `slug` instead of name - it's important to use safe words here. So you can create a `slug` based on the `name` of a stream. Also, they should not override other routes.